# How to adjust power for 1st & 2nd gear in classic 350?

Tags: clutch, performance, gears, enfield-bullet

i am facing loss of power with 1st & 2nd gear while accelerating after changing gears. As soon as RPM goes high the power becomes stable.
I want to know that which type of setting should be done for best pickup performance.

Comment: It's an old bike, you should not mess with engine, keep it classic. You can perform the engine, you can tune it up for your favorite revolutions (lower RPM range will have less power), you can play with inlet and exhaust timing, compression ratio, change different diameter and quality inlet system.. But it takes a lot of work and money. It is not a single screw that will adjust a power on your bike..

Comment: @ArtursBolsunovskis, That is incorrect and not factual. Asking to keep it classic is an opinion.

Comment: Is this issue new, did it occur after you changed something or has it always been like that? I would like at the carburetor, improper AF ratio can cause this kind of behaviour.